# Angular popup not working from TS file, but works from HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application having a single button.

On click of the button I will be able to open a popup

**index-component.html (Landing Page)**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)=warning.show()>
</button>
<app-modal #warning>
</app-modal>
```

**index-component.ts**

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './model-component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./model-component.css']
    })

  export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
    public show(): void {
   this.visible = true;

   setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);  
 }
}
```

**model-component.html (Popup Component)**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">    
    <div class="modal-content">
     Some data for popup here..........
    </div>
</div>
```

The above execution of opening popup is happening through the line

`(click)=warning.show()`

Which is working perfectly.

Now I need to move this call to TS file.

So, in the index-component.ts I need to call `warning.show()`

But, I am unable to get the instance of `#warning` in TS file.

How will I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an instance of a local variable defined in Angular using `@viewChild` like this -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)=getInstance()>
</button>


export class IndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('warning') warning: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.warning);
  }
  getInstance() {
    console.log(this.warning);
  }
}
```

[Working Example for the same](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tee7ha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @ViewChild('warning') warning: any; its says unused label

Comment: @SmartestVEGA Please check my updated answer with example

Comment: view child should be inside export

Comment: Opps, just posted by mistake, anyways Code written properly on example you can check

Comment: what if I need to call it from something.service.ts here i don't have any html page to put the  </app-modal>

Comment: Then I guess you need to pass the reference via params to that method.

Comment: Could you please update here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tee7ha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './model-component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./model-component.css']
    })

  export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('warning') warning: any;

 onButtonClick() {
    this.warning.show()
 }
}
```

Here Html button click should be **(click)="onButtonClick()"**

or You can pass the reference as a parameter from .html file

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './model-component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./model-component.css']
    })

  export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {


 onButtonClick(warning:any) {
    warning.show()
 }
}
```

Here Html button click should be **(click)="onButtonClick(warning)"**

Comment: Good, But passing reference as params is not a good approach somewhere, when we have options available.

Comment: @PardeepJain, Thank You but If there is no use of warning component else where , no need to declare a variable and assign (code minimization. memory waste). Sorry If am wrong

Comment: what if I need to call it from something.service.ts here i don't have any html page to put the </app-modal>

Comment: @ViewChild('warning') warning: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
this.something.service.warningPopup = this.warning;
  }